# Advantages of using panel data structure when estimating causal effects consistently

Tags: estimation, panel-data, causality

What are the main advantages of using panel data structure compared to the pure cross-sectional data when we want to estimate causal effect of some phenomenon consistently?

I know what the general advantages of using panel data structure are e.g. multi-dimensional data (combination of cross sectional and time series data), more accurate and realistic, more information to work with, more sample variability, etc. But, how are these advantages related to consistency and estimation of causal effects?